# Handling corrupted xml file in Spring Batch using StaxEventItemReader as reader

Tags: spring, batch-file

I am using StaxEventItemReader for reading xml file as below:

```
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="Basket" />
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:xml/basket1.xml" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="reportUnmarshaller" />
</bean>
```

If xml file is in corrupted form, I need to move file to "failed" folder. However, I couldn't find any handle for this.

Please provide any help for this.